# Before and after images for each entry

Tags: matrix, grid, channel-images

I have a channel for "projects", and each project has multiple before and after images associated with it. What would be the best way of organizing this in terms of channel fields? I'm currently using the Channel Images (CI) addon to manage images.

I thought using EE's Grid or P&T's Matrix would be ideal, but CI doesn't seem to be compatible with either. I could technically use Grid with the File fieldtype, but it obviously wouldn't have the adaptive capabilities of CI.

The only thing I could think of was to create two separate CI fields, one for before and one for after, but how would I link each image to its counterpart?

Comment: What are you referring to with the abbreviation CE?

Comment: @jrothafer Sorry, meant CI. Was reading another post about CE Image at the time.